# Your age in months according to your date of birth

Tags: c++

So for a school project I'm trying to make a program that calculates your age in months according to your date of birth. I'm writing this in C++. Please don't mind the use of unnecessary/extra code as I'm still learning. Please note: variable names and notes are in **Dutch**. When using for example 9/6/1996 as my birth date the program works fine, but when I use 9/6/1969 it returns 30, in other words it's not working **and the problem seems to have something to do with the year**. Any ideas on how to solve this? Thank you in advance.
**My code:**

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;



int main() {

   int huidigJaar = 2014;
   int huidigeMaand = 8;
   int huidigeDag = 19;
   int geboorteJaar = 1;
   int geboorteMaand = 1;
   int geboorteDag = 1;
   int totaalMaanden = 1;

   cout << "Wat is je geboortejaar?";
   cin >> geboorteJaar;
   cout << "Wat is je geboortemaand?";
   cin >> geboorteMaand;
   cout << "Wat is je geboortedag?";
   cin >> geboorteDag;

   int verschilJaar = huidigJaar - geboorteJaar - 1; // niet iedereen is al jarig geweest

  //kijken of het jaar erbij mag en totaal aantal maanden uitrekenen
   if ( geboorteMaand < huidigeMaand ) { //de persoon is dit jaar al jarig geweest

     verschilJaar = verschilJaar + 1;

     if ( geboorteDag <= huidigeDag ) {

       totaalMaanden = verschilJaar * 12 + ( huidigeMaand - geboorteMaand ); //de huidige maand komt erbij

     }else {

       totaalMaanden = verschilJaar * 12 + ( huidigeMaand - geboorteMaand ) - 1; //de huidige maand gaat eraf

     }

   }else if ( geboorteMaand == huidigeMaand ) {

     if ( geboorteDag <= huidigeDag ) {

        verschilJaar = verschilJaar + 1;
        totaalMaanden = verschilJaar * 12;  //heel jaar

     }else {

        totaalMaanden = verschilJaar * 12 + 11; //er komt niet een heel jaar bij maar wel 11 maanden, omdat de huidige maand niet meetelt

     }
   }else {

     if ( geboorteDag <= huidigeDag ) {

        totaalMaanden = verschilJaar * 12 + huidigeMaand + ( 12 - geboorteMaand ); //de persoon moet nog jarig worden, dus geen jaar erbij maar wel de maanden na zijn verjaardag

     }else {  
        totaalMaanden = verschilJaar * 12 + huidigeMaand + ( 12 - geboorteMaand ) - 1; //zelfde maar dan een maand eraf omdat deze maand niet als een maand gerekend kan worden

     }

   }



return totaalMaanden;



}//main
```

Comment: Write your calculation down on a piece of paper and reproduce it in your programming language.

Comment: can you use `std::chrono` for your school project?

Comment: Ask your instructor to demonstrate using a debugger.  With a debugger, you can see variables change and execute your program statement by statement.  Very useful, especially in cases like this.

Comment: Thank you both. I'll do the calculation on paper again, might help. The std::chrono option was optional for the project, but as using the 19/9/2014 date as the current date option was also an option and seemed more easy I went with that.

Comment: Y so complex? http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/918cbeb9df0c5c7f

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've run your code with my debugger, and I find the following **CORRECT** values:

- for 1996 6 9  a value of 218
- for 1969 6 9  a value of 542

However your code does not display them, but it **returns them from main()**. This is a bad practice:  main() shall return an error code.

The value returned to operating system is managed in a **[system dependent](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Exit_status)** manner: under POSIX, bash, or windows cmd, the values can be only between 0 and 255.

If you calculate 542 modulo 256 you'll find 30.

Please if you report here issues with C++ code, be sure that the problem is in C++ code and not in some shell script arround it.

Answer (score 1):

I dont C++ or speak dutch, but i can run you through the psudo-code i'd use. From what i see, your code looks a lot more complex than it should be...unless its because of the dutch:

1. enter the DOB as a string, then tokenize as a date object it using
   some C++ Date class,
2. parse the month and year as an int,
3. use the Date Class to get today's date, toknize it as well, or if the option is
   available, get the month & year alone
4. get the difference between the year entered and the year provided and multiply by 12
5. Subtract the month of birth from 12 to determine the age at the end of the year of birth.
6. get the int of month of "today".
7. by now, all your values would be in months. ADD them all together--that should be an answer.

Comment: For step 1, he has users enter year, then month, then day-of-month explicitly, bypassing the tokenization.  Also "today's date" is allowed to be hardcoded to 19/9/2014.  Also, your pseudocode doesn't compensate for day-of-month.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to respond, I got this solved but will take a look at your way of doing it!